# ¿Alguien sabe como puedo actualizar la versión mas reciente de angular en una app de Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetcore

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2022 y he creado una aplicación Angular con Net Core, pero la versión que tengo de angular es la 15,2,0 y la que me pone Visual Studio 2022 es la 12.

He buscado como actualizar a la nueva versión pero cuando lo hago ya no me corre la aplicación si alguien sabe que pasos debo de hacer o que ficheros debo de modificar lo agradeceré.